# How to detect style of list (bullet or numbering) in python docx?

Tags: python, xml, list, python-docx

I need to read the Docx document and detect the list type.
In paragraph style not have information of list type.
I detect list by

```py
if "<w:numId" in paragraph._p.xml:
    pass#this is list
```

But I don't know how to get the type of list. Maybe have some information in **numbering**?
For example:

```py
...
from docx.oxml import numbering

for paragraoh in document.paragraphs:
    if "<w:numId" in paragraph._p.xml:
        if numbering.style == "Numbering":
            pass#this is numbering 
        else:
            pass#this is bullet
```

For reading Docx, I use **docx** library for python3
How to get the type of list?